# Merge list of dict and add new values

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, merge

I need merge 2 list of dicts by conditions without using pandas

x1 - fact values

```
x1 = [{'id': '94ffe1d6-0afa-11ec-b139-4cd98f4d62e3',
  'fact_group': '0.05',
  'probability': 0.2},
 {'id': '86ae0229-0af8-11ec-be8c-4cd98f847094',
  'fact_group': '0.05',
  'probability': 0.56},
 {'id': '867ef7ac-0af8-11ec-be8c-4cd98f847094',
  'fact_group': '0.2',
  'probability': 0.31},
 {'id': '211bc00c-0af6-11ec-b139-4cd98f4d62e3',
  'fact_group': '0.2',
  'probability': 0.96}]
```

x2 - list of dict with intervals probability to labels point

```
x2 = [{'group': 0.05,
  'predict_labels': 0,
  'predict_intervals_min': 0.00,
  'predict_intervals_max': 0.6},
 {'group': 0.05,
  'predict_labels': 1,
  'predict_intervals_min': 0.6,
  'predict_intervals_max': 1.0},
 {'group': 0.2,
  'predict_labels': 2,
  'predict_intervals_min': 0.0,
  'predict_intervals_max': 0.45},
 {'group': 0.2,
  'predict_labels': 3,
  'predict_intervals_min': 0.45,
  'predict_intervals_max': 1.0}]
```

I need to merge them by `x1['fact_group'] & x2['group']`
and `x1['probability']>=x2['predict_intervals_min']`
and `x1['probability']<x2['predict_intervals_max']`

Expected: update x1 by x2['predict_labels'] by thresholds and group

```
x3 = [{'id': '94ffe1d6-0afa-11ec-b139-4cd98f4d62e3',
  'predict_labels': 1,
  'fact_group': '0.05',
 'predict_labels': 0,
  'probability': 0.2},
 {'id': '86ae0229-0af8-11ec-be8c-4cd98f847094',
  'predict_labels': 1,
  'fact_group': '0.05',
  'predict_labels': 0,
  'probability': 0.56},
 {'id': '867ef7ac-0af8-11ec-be8c-4cd98f847094',
  'fact_group': '0.2',
  'predict_labels': 2,
  'probability': 0.31},
 {'id': '211bc00c-0af6-11ec-b139-4cd98f4d62e3',
  'fact_group': '0.2',
  'predict_labels': 3,
  'probability': 0.96}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this simple solution:

```
result = []

for y1 in x1:
    for y2 in x2:
        if (y1['fact_group'] == str(y2['group'])) and \
           (y1['probability'] >= y2['predict_intervals_min']) and \
           (y1['probability'] <  y2['predict_intervals_max']):
            d = y1
            d['predict_labels'] = y2['predict_labels']
            result.append(d)

print(result)
```